# java main block on sun.usagetracker.UsageTrackerClient.registerUsage

Tags: java, java-8, block

my java app sametimes will block on this stack serveral minite，who known why
it is not necessarily
java version: 8u_152(b16)

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007efcec027800 nid=0x2bbda runnable [0x00007efcf5744000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
        at sun.usagetracker.UsageTrackerClient.registerUsage(UsageTrackerClient.java:479)
        at sun.usagetracker.UsageTrackerClient.setupAndTimestamp(UsageTrackerClient.java:342)
        at sun.usagetracker.UsageTrackerClient.access$000(UsageTrackerClient.java:96)
        at sun.usagetracker.UsageTrackerClient$4.run(UsageTrackerClient.java:364)
        at sun.usagetracker.UsageTrackerClient$4.run(UsageTrackerClient.java:359)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.usagetracker.UsageTrackerClient.run(UsageTrackerClient.java:359)
        at sun.misc.PostVMInitHook.trackJavaUsage(PostVMInitHook.java:29)
        at sun.misc.PostVMInitHook.run(PostVMInitHook.java:21)
```

Comment: Java 8 Update 152 is ancient, the latest for Java 8 is Java 8 Update 321. For all we know, this is a bug in that version, so I recommend that you first update to the latest Java 8.

Comment: Another issue is that the `UsageTrackerClient` source code is not part of the standard OpenJDK codebase, and I can't locate it via Google search.  (I think this is deliberate on Oracle's part ...)  So it will be difficult for anyone (other than an Oracle or 3rd-party Vendor Java Support Engineer) to figure what is going on.  Have you contacted Oracle / vendor support?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for you help, can you tell me the bug details, or give me the bug link.

Comment: My point is that I recommend that you try to reproduce this on the latest Java 8 instead. That is the golden rule when confronted with errors: if you're using an older version, try the latest point release to see if that fixes your problem.